# Set up shotgun to start thin with its debug flag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, thin, shotgun

I am trying to get the debugger gem working with shotgun, and for the debugger to work I need the thin server to be started with "Debugging ON".

If I run either:

```
shotgun -p 1378 -s thin -d -o 0.0.0.0
shotgun -p 1378 -s thin --debug -o 0.0.0.0
```

I get shotgun starting with the $DEBUG ruby variable being set to true, instead of having the thin server being started with the debug flag on.

If I run:

```
shotgun -pp 1378 -s "thin --debug" -o 0.0.0.0
```

I get an error.  Is there another way to run this, or some way to tell thin to start in debugger mode when the environment is set to development?

Comment: Never used ruby, but a language which let you use a shotgun, deserves a +1 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [`-d` and `--debug` options are being interpreted by Shotgun](https://github.com/rtomayko/shotgun/blob/0.9/bin/shotgun#L23), rather than Thin, and that is what is setting `$DEBUG` to true.

Thin’s command line flag to turn on [debugging is `-D` or `--debug`](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/blob/v1.4.1/lib/thin/runner.rb#L133) and this [sets `Thin::Logging.debug` to true](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/blob/v1.4.1/lib/thin/runner.rb#L174). You can’t use the `thin` command line options (sine the command line is being read by `shotgun` which launches the server), but you can set this variable with some normal Ruby code. One way to do this would be with [a `shotgun.rb` file](http://rtomayko.github.com/shotgun/#PRELOADING) that requires Thin and changes the setting:

```
require 'thin'
Thin::Logging.debug = true
```

(You might want to put this in a `begin...rescue...block` and rescue the LoadError in case Thin isn’t available.)

The output without this file:

```
$ shotgun
== Shotgun/Thin on http://127.0.0.1:9393/
>> Thin web server (v1.4.1 codename Chromeo)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 127.0.0.1:9393, CTRL+C to stop
```

and with the file:

```
$ shotgun
== Shotgun/Thin on http://127.0.0.1:9393/
>> Thin web server (v1.4.1 codename Chromeo)
>> Debugging ON
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 127.0.0.1:9393, CTRL+C to stop
```

As far as I can tell, this setting only affects the verbosity of Thin’s logging, and doesn’t have anything to do with the [Debugger gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/debugger).

Comment: This is out of date, the debugging option is actually -D (yes, capital D) which is right there in the source..but for the click lazy!

Comment: @MBHNYC Well spotted – thanks. I’ve updated the answer to clarify what’s going on, I think the rest of it is okay.